# Data/information on ferrocyanide production

Tags: products, environment

I am working in the modelling and environmental evaluation of redox flow batteries based on Anthraquinone and ferrocyanide. Currently I am having difficulties in finding information on how ferrocyanide is produced, for example as Potassium Ferrocyanide.

Does anyone know where I can find information or data concerning its production, if possible at an industrial scale.